# Update react use state synchronously

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syncfusion

I need to get click coordinate using an event listener and store it using react hook usestate so i can use it to display a menu.

it seems like usestate is asynchronous and the value update only in the second click.

My code below :

```
const [xPosition, setXPosition] = useState<number>(0);
const [yPosition, setYPosition] = useState<number>(0);
let cmenu;


const btnClick = () => {
document.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  let x = event.pageX;
  let y = event.pageY;
  setYPosition(y);
  setXPosition(x);
});
cmenu.open(yPosition, xPosition);
  };
```

Thanks

**EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION **

cmenu.open(yPosition, xPosition); needs to be called inside btnClick function that I'm using for a react Syncfusion library to open a contextualMenu when the function is called.

The document.addEventListener("click", function (event) ... is to get the coordinate of the clicked area so I can open contextualMenu in that position.

Thanks!

Comment: Fist call to `btnClick` will only register new event (again and again) and only second click on document will trigger this event. Why not bind this event on body `<body onClick={innerPartOfEventFunction}`

Comment: Why are you using `document.addEventListener` in React?  What calls `btnClick`?  This doesn't appear to have anything to do with `useState`, it seems like you're just confused on (1) how to use React at all and (2) what operation should be performed when clicking your button.

Comment: According to your post, you don't need to store the coordinates in a state, isn't it? But if you need to do so, please update your question, as it is unclear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: https://react.dev/learn/responding-to-events

Comment: @David I'm using document.addEventListener to get coordinates of the clicked area to be able to open a Syncfusion contextualMenu in that exact position

Comment: @Zetsuu: But why do you *have to* use `document.addEventListener`?  Why can't you attach that click event handler in the markup like one normally does in React?  How are you invoking `btnClick`?  Is that not a click handler used in the markup? Aside from that... What is the actual problem that you're trying to describe? After you invoke `btnClick` (which attaches your click handler to `document`), when you next click somewhere in the document (not on whatever invoked `btnClick`), what happens?  Which event *should* call `cmenu.open()`? Maybe you confused yourself with inconsistent indentation?

Comment: The problem is that use state updates it's value on the second click because its asynchronous, I need it to update the value on the first click

Comment: @Zetsuu: On the second or first click of *what*, specifically?  The code shown has *two* click handlers.  Which implies that you plan to click *two* things.  So it's really not clear what you're even trying to accomplish or what problem you're trying to describe.  This has nothing to do with synchronous vs. asynchronous functionality, and your assumption of that is getting in your way of actually understanding whatever problem you're trying to describe.  Do you want to update state values in `btnClick`?  Or do you want to update them in your `document.addEventListener` click handler?

Comment: @Zetsuu: Perhaps instead of trying to vaguely describe what you assume the problem is, can you instead update the question to include a [mcve] as a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) which demonstrates the problem, and indicate specifically what problem you are observing in that example?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use these coordinates immediately within your event listener. Heres a more straightforward version of your code:

```
  const [xPosition, setXPosition] = useState(0);
  const [yPosition, setYPosition] = useState(0);
  let cmenu;

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleClick = (event) => {
      setXPosition(event.pageX);
      setYPosition(event.pageY);
      cmenu.open(event.pageY, event.pageX); // Use the coordinates directly
    };

    document.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
    return () => document.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
  }, []);
```

There may be some issue with the parenthesis but hope so it can give you general idea about your problem

Comment: Thank you but I have already tried this, and I cannot use the coordinates directly because the cmenu.open function needs to be inside btnClick function that is called in a react syncfusion cumponent (to open a menu when clicked), and as you know I cannot also call the btnClick function inside the useEffect hook.

Answer (score 0):

Working with React, it's important to understand that state updates may not be synchronous. This can cause problems when attempting to access state variables immediately after modifying them, as they might not have been updated yet. To address this issue, the useEffect method in React can be utilized. Please refer to the code snippet and sample to demonstrate its usage.

```
  const [xPosition, setXPosition] = useState(0);
  const [yPosition, setYPosition] = useState(0);
  const [openMenu, setOpenMenu] = useState(false);
  const contextMenuRef = useRef(null);
 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (openMenu && contextMenuRef.current) {
      contextMenuRef.current.open(yPosition, xPosition);
      setOpenMenu(false); // Reset openMenu state after opening the menu
    }
  }, [openMenu, yPosition, xPosition]);
 
  function btnClick() {
    document.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      let x = event.pageX;
      let y = event.pageY;
      setXPosition(x);
      setYPosition(y);
      setOpenMenu(true);
    });
  }
```

Sample link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jli6nc-reagfq?file=index.js

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you try to achieve here, but the onClick function from a button provide an event parameter:

```
const btnClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => {
    cmenu.open(event.clientX, event.clientY);
  };
```

you should call this function like this for instance:

```
  <button onClick={btnClick}>click</button>
```